# Limit number of pages in pagination

Tags: php, mysqli, pagination

I am trying to create my very first "news page". Instead of scrolling to eternity I am trying to make a simple pagination, for better user experience.

So far, I have managed to:

- Show `X` number of news per site
- Show pages at the bottom, to scroll through

What I am missing is that, if there are a lot of news a huge amount of pages will be shown. It would be much nicer, if I was able to limit the amount of pages shown:

For instance; if I'm at page 5, I should be able to see, Page 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8.

How can I implement that to my code? I am very uncertain of this.

**My code**

```
<?

$sqlDos = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM articles";


$rs_result = mysqli_query($con, $sqlDos);  
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($rs_result);  
$total_records = $row[0];  

$total_pages = ceil($total_records / $limit);  
$pagLink = "<div class='pagination'>"; 


for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {  
    if ($i == $page) {
        $pagLink .= "<a class='active' href='#'>".$i."</a>"; 
    } else {
        $pagLink .= " <a href='news.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a>";
    }
};


echo $pagLink . "</div>"; 

?>
```

I hope you will take your time to explain how this can be done, as this is my first project of the like.

Thank you very much! :-)

**EDIT**
I have only shown the code that is relevant, therefore some variables maybe missing to show what they are - let me know if you think something is missing :)

Comment: if the current page is 2, What are all the pages you would like to display to the user

Comment: @Tarun Then it should only be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 - so maximum of three pages to each side, but if the user is only at page 2 as you say, there should only be one page lower (page 1) :)

Comment: Okay, I Posted the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post current page number to the PHP script and apply the following logic:

```
$startPage = 1;
$endPage   =  $page+ 3;
if($currentPageNo > 3){
   $startPage =  $page - 3;
}

for ($i=$startPage; $i<=$endPage; $i++) {  
    if ($i == $page) {
        $pagLink .= "<a class='active' href='#'>".$i."</a>"; 
    } else {
        $pagLink .= " <a href='news.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a>";
    }
};
```

Comment: thank you for your help! It was very simple to understand what needed to be done - thanks!